# Amazon sagemaker. SKlearn estimator vs Tensorflow estimator - why requirements_file is not present in one of them?

Tags: python, requirements, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking at definitions of two estimators SKLearn and Tensorflow in Amazon Sagemaker:

[SKLearn](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sagemaker.sklearn.html)

[Tensorflow](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sagemaker.tensorflow.html)

```
class sagemaker.sklearn.estimator.SKLearn(entry_point, framework_version='0.20.0', source_dir=None, hyperparameters=None, py_version='py3', image_name=None, **kwargs)

class sagemaker.tensorflow.estimator.TensorFlow(training_steps=None, evaluation_steps=None, checkpoint_path=None, py_version='py2', framework_version=None, model_dir=None, requirements_file='', image_name=None, script_mode=False, distributions=None, **kwargs)
```

Tensorflow has requirements_file parameter, while SKLearn does not. Is there reason why? How can I add `requirements.txt` to SKLearn estimator?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar usecase, while [this issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container/issues/5) states that they will be supporting it, I found that if you keep [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file besides your entry point file, it downloads the required dependencies.